# Combining and filtering two 'select' with BeautifulSoup, is it possible?

Tags: python-3.x, select, beautifulsoup

here is my predicament:
What I wanna do is to get newly posts in a table named "theme".

this is what i have for new posts, new posts has a sticker:

```
new_posts = soup.select('tbody:has(.threadpages [src="images/new.gif"]), '
                        'tbody:has(.threadpages [src="images/new1.gif"]), '
                        'tbody:has(.threadpages [src="images/new2.gif"])')
```

this is what I have for the "theme" table:

```
theme_posts = soup.select('table:has(font:contains("theme")), '
```

is there a way I can combine both? I tried do table first, and then do new posts, it gives me Error saying

```
ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
```

can anyone help me out with it?

Answer (score 1):

I worked around yesterday, and I found a way, which is working pretty well. Here is the codes:

```
theme = soup.select('table:has(font:contains("there"))')
    for item in theme:
        for new in item.select('tbody:has(.threadpages [src="images/new.gif"]), '
                               'tbody:has(.threadpages [src="images/new1.gif"]), '
                               'tbody:has(.threadpages [src="images/new2.gif"])'):
```

and then whatever codes follow...